# Query in a large table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, large-data

I have a table with two columns ( ID1, ID2). These two columns together create the primary key. The problem is that I have nearly 30,000,000 rows in this table. When I send query to this table it take a lot of time and most of the times the query fails. Is there any way to solve this problem? should I add any other kind of index?

Comment: Do you always query on both `ID1` and `ID2`? I assume that you do have an index on `ID1, ID2`, right?

Comment: yes, you need an index to make the primary key... however, can you show the rest of your query / where, criteria, etc... that would better help direct what index may be more optimal for you.

Comment: I have index for primary key. Should I have any other index for each column separately to enhance the performance?

Comment: We'll need to see the query, and possibly the table schema and EXPLAIN result. InnoDB?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID1) FROM TABLE

Answer (score -1):

Do you have an index on the key? If not, build one (system resources permitting). If you have an index and want to use it properly, you need to make sure the fields mentioned in the `WHERE` predicate of your query are included in the index.

Comment: ID1 and ID2 create primary key index together. should I have any other index on each of them separately?

Comment: No, that would be redundant and would consume more system resources.